# Entity Framework Fluent migration default value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to generate automatically a default value for metadata columns 
in my code first database. It seems like code first migration fluent api does not handle 
HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)

Every table in my DB has a "CREATION_DATE" column using default value "getdate()". In my EntityTypeConfiguration i try to use:

```
Property(p => p.CREATION_DATE).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

This is generated for the migration:

```
CREATION_DATE = c.DateTime(nullable: false)
```

I can manually add defaultValueSql: "getdate()", but I don't want to do this every migration. I did write a SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator for this, but it just does not seem to generate the default value.

```
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TheModel>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        SetSqlGenerator(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, new CustomMigrationSqlGenerator());
    }
```

and in the CustomMigrationSqlGenerator class

```
        protected override void Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
    {
        SetDefaultDate(createTableOperation.Columns);
        base.Generate(createTableOperation);
    }
```

The default value is not generated with or without the CustomMigrationSqlGenerator.

Am I missing something? I read on forums that it was an issue at some point, but the posts date back from 2010-2012.

*Edit

Content of SetDefaultDate

```
    private static void SetDefaultDate(IEnumerable<ColumnModel> columns)
    {
        foreach (var item in columns)
        {
            SetDefaultDate(item);
        }
    }
    private static void SetDefaultDate(ColumnModel column)
    {
        if (column.Type.Equals(System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.PrimitiveTypeKind.DateTime))
        {
            column.DefaultValueSql = "getdate()";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that is the general approach: http://lancelarsen.com/entity-framework-code-first-computed-getdate/ What we do is mark our entities that have a create and modify date with an interface we can override in SaveChanges() to set the dates in EF. http://benjii.me/2014/03/track-created-and-modified-fields-automatically-with-entity-framework-code-first/

Comment: I know I could use EF to populate those fields, but my question is about generating the correct sql using code first migrations and I cannot get it to generate

CREATION_DATE = c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "getdate()");

I tried with dataAnnotations, even though I won't mix annotations and fluent api, but it still only generate

CREATION_DATE = c.DateTime(nullable: false);

Comment: What does your SetDefaultDate() look like?

Comment: Content of SetDefaultDate() added to original post.

Comment: What if you change the order of the lines inside the `Generate()` method?

Comment: Does not change anything. I also tried to use "PropertyModel" instead of "ColumnModel" parameter types. I also tried to compare by column.name instead of column.type, still nothing